# How to get a record from a different controller

Tags: java, groovy, grails

I am trying to grab a record from one controller and pass it into another controller. On the main page, I use the CaseRecordController.groovy to populate information by ID like this:

```
def show() {
    def caseRecordInstance

    try {
        def id = Long.parseLong(params.id)
        caseRecordInstance = CaseRecord.findById(id)
    }...
}
```

And then it goes to the next page, BaseLineController.groovy which uses the same kind of code to get the page's information:

```
def show() {
    def baselineInstance
    def caseRecordInstance

    if(params.id) baselineInstance = Baseline.findById(Long.parseLong(params.id))

    try {
        def id = Long.parseLong(params.id)
        caseRecordInstance = CaseRecord.findById(id)
    }...
}
```

...which works for getting that controllers ID ( which is different because it uses a different controller ). But I want to grab the ID from the previous controller, the CaseRecordController, to get that information.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Groovys web capabilities, but usually, you expose a REST endpoint with a controller (e.g. spring-boot-web-mvc). And the way to call it is by using an HTTP client on which you submit a non/-blocking GET request to the endpoint, which, when successful returns the offered data fro the endpoint.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you're basically calling 2 http endpoints from your UI/client, right? If so, the canonical way to pass data around would be passing it back to the caller (i.e. your client) and from there to the 2nd call. Of course, if it's a lot of data you could store it somewhere (e.g. a common cache or DB) and return pass around a key - but you'd normally want your controllers to be stateless. If you really need stateful controllers (that keep data in their memory) then you'd still pass around some id to get the correct instance.

Comment: Why do you want to keep state like this?  It sounds very fragile. Have you considered passing the two IDs into your controller via the request instead (e.g. setup an url-mapping)?

Comment: @cfrick Yeah I would rather have a more solidified way to do it, but the bottom answer works. I did not try url-mapping, I'll look into it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Put the id into the `session` and grab it from anywhere else at any time.
2. Use the `flash`-scope to do the same, but only once.

This is how it can look like:

```
def showA() {
   session.caseRecordId = params.id
   // or
   flash.caseRecordId = params.id
}

def showB() {
   println session.caseRecordId
   // or
   println flash.caseRecordId // only once
}
```

Comment: This will work thanks